# How to automatically identify which value is stored in specific location of transaction input , given a smart contract source code and ABI?

Tags: solidity, transactions, abi

For example, a function's name and parameters are given as following:

```
function batchTransfer(address[] _receivers, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
```

Then I want to get a python dictionary whose key is the first location of the value in transaction input, and value is the corresponding value, for example:

```
p {};

p["0"] = 0x34672534; // the function signature

p["4"] = 'offset'; // the offset of '_receivers' value

p["36"] = '_value';

p["4+offset"] = '_receivers.length'; // the length of '_receivers'

p["4+offset+1*32"] = '_receivers[1]'

p["4+offset+2*32"] = '_receivers[2]'
```

Note: since when reaching this stage, only contract source codes and ABI were given, and there are no concrete inputs, namely, I should derive this dictionary by statically analyzing source codes or ABI, so the location can be expressed by expressions as shown above.

So, is there any way to implement such a parser to get this map?

Or is there already an existing one?

Comment: A `mapping(string -> string)` doesn't seem appropriate here. To begin with, neither `0x34672534` nor `_value` is of type `string`. Please refine your question.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote my question.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use this https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder or even better https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameters

Comment: I searched the source codes of 'decodeparameters' function in Web3. but i found it was imported from another unknown package, could you please tell me  where i can find the codes of 'decodeparameters'.

Comment: Here I think https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/2.x/packages/web3-eth-abi/src/AbiCoder.js#L143

Comment: This page also uses a packed function 'decodeParameter()' imported from another package. Finally, I found this package was 'ethers' (https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/getting-started.html) but it's impemented by JS. I wander if there is any straight way to implement my expected function without refering abicoders